# Laravel api with paginate() does not work with reach native

Tags: laravel, react-native, laravel-api

I have a laravel api in which I added `->paginate()` so I can paginate, and use it by fetching the laravel api  in my react native app, so as to apply a load more data when the app is scrolled.

This my laravel api

```
public function allPerson(Request $request) {
  return Person::where('active', 'online')->paginate($request->input('results', 10));
}
```

Api URL

`https://housedata.com/allperson?page=2`

React Native

```
  const [personData, setPerson] = React.useState([]);

    const getPerson = () => {
        axios.get('https://housedata.com/allperson?page=2')
            .then(response => {
                setPerson(response.data)    
                console.log(response.data);
            });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getPerson();
    }, []);


    <FlatList
        data={personData}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <Text>{item.person_name}</Text>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
```

When I check `console.log(response.data);` I see the data is been fetch.

Also when I change `->paginate()` to `get()` it is showing the data and working, how can I fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the get and paginate method returns data differently the get method returns the data directly where as the paginate method will return a paginate object which contains a data property so to access it you have to do

response.data.data

```
axios.get('https://housedata.com/allperson?page=2')
        .then(response => {
            setPerson(response.data.data)    // <-- change this
            console.log(response.data.data);
        });
```

Comment: i think this solution works, else can you show your result from console.

Comment: Thanks @tashif muzaffar for the response, I will try it out.